# How to implement a button for emoji (like Hangouts)?

Tags: android, unicode, emoji, google-hangouts

How is it possible to implement a button that opens the emoji keyboard like in Hangouts?

I don't mean the standard emoji key inside the keyboard that appears when using android:inputType="textShortMessage". It should be a separate button inside the apps layout.

I'd appreciate any help or hints your guys can give. Thanks :)

[image: Emoji button]

Comment: Have You any solution regarding this question

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm using android:inputType="textShortMessage" for now... Android users are using less Emoji than iOS users with this solution :(